# How can I place <a> tags over another (greater) <a> tag?

Tags: html, image, anchor, hyperlink

Here's the case: I have a series of thumbnails in a page, and I would like to display several keywords over each image when the user hovers with the cursor. Each of those keywords are anchor tags that point to a search query. And each thumbnail (the image) should also be clickable (through the empty spaces that the keywords leave) and point to a specific page.

I have everything already coded, I'm just missing a way to display the keyword anchors over the image anchors. I already tried with an onclick="window.location.href=..." but when the user clicks the keyword, the onclick is also triggered (for instance: if I ctrl+click on a keyword, i get the keyword search on a different window, but the main window content changes as well).

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: so basically, is it that the onclick event on keyword anchor is cacading down to the onclick event of the thumbnail??

Comment: What's your HTML, CSS, and javascript? There's probably a workaround with valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite common and can definitely be done with plain HTML and CSS. You can also do it with JavaScript, but I prefer to avoid doing so if possible.

This example is perfectly valid HTML/CSS and should have no weird browser rendering issues (even as far back as IE 6).

http://jsfiddle.net/2JD76/1/

Basically you have a containing element, in this case a div, which has your linked thumbnail and linked keywords. They're hidden by default and only shown when the containing div is hovered.

The linked thumbnail is absolutely positioned so that it's taken out of the page flow which then allows the linked keywords to appear on top. I then use z-indexes to make sure that the keywords are always on a layer that is higher than that of the linked thumbnail.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir for your response, it was of great help indeed. Have yourself a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. It is illegal html.
Attach a click handler that changes the current location instead of the "greater ".

Answer (score 0):

I was going to answer with a long reply but, well check out my Jsfiddle here. I was trying to solve something before and well...check it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/KSt6a/

If you look at the code, its doing exactly what you are describing.

On my Jsfiddle, theres a div box with space for an image(this is wher YOUR image would go), *The image is on the code but not on the jsfiddle so youll see the alt tag*....Anyways so,  on mouse-over, it brings up another div with text dynamically created inside of it.

All you have to do is replace the image content with your own image, then Insert the links/keywords links you want into this line

```
.prepend('<div class="portSecRollOver"><div class="portSecInner"></div></div>');
```

and stick your words **in between** the `<div class="portSecInner"> **YOUR WORDS HERE** </div>` line

And change the CSS to fit your needs.

oh AND ps, DELETE this line (below) which is the one that dynamically appends text inside of "portSecInner", since your going to insert your own words, then you dont need this line.

```
$(this).find('.portSecInner').html("<h3 class='h34roll'>" + $(this).find('img').attr("alt") + "</h3>");
```